# ADB Shell commands for Network RI Status and Icons

Tags: android, shell, sqlite, adb, ri

Is there an adb command to check the RI (roaming indicator) status or if the device has an active cell signal (no service, 1, 2, 3 bars)?
I am not an android programmer, so my knowledge is really limited to adb commands.
Any suggestions where I should look?
My guess is that it would somehow be accessible through

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/<package_name>/databases/
```

Am I on the right path here?